# QNetwork error when use Qt lib with native JNI Android application

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I have the simple Qt lib that makes http request like this:

```
QNetworkAccessManager networkAccessManager;
QNetworkRequest request{QUrl("http://www.google.ru")};
QNetworkReply * reply = networkAccessManager.get(request);
...
```

All works fine when i run it on Android devices (`armeabi-v7a` and `x86`) diractly from Qt Creator. But i want to use it inside android native application with `NDK` and `JNI`. In this case it works only on `armeabi-v7a`  devices and with Android from version 6.0. If i run android application with this lib on `x86` device it crash with next message:

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 11830
>   (itekllc.testjni)

And it occurs on this line of code inside my Qt lib:

```
QNetworkReply * reply = networkAccessManager.get(request);
```

This is my `communication.cpp` file in native android project:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "QCoreApplication"
#include "testandroidthreadslib.h"

#ifndef _Included_com_navitekllc_testjni_CppWrapper
#define _Included_com_navitekllc_testjni_CppWrapper

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_navitekllc_testjni_CppWrapper_testNetwork(JNIEnv *env, jclass type) {
    TestAndroidThreadsLib testLib;
    testLib.run();
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

This is my `.java` file to call `.cpp` function:

```
public class CppWrapper {
    public static native void testNetwork();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("communication");
    }
}
```

This is my `build.gradle` experemental gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {

    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            QtStaticLibrary {
                headers.srcDir file("..PathToLib/TestAndroidThreadsLib").absolutePath
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    def myStaticLibPath = "src/main/jniLibs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libTestAndroidThreadsLib.a"
                    staticLibraryFile = file("${myStaticLibPath}")
                }
            }
            QCoreSharedLibrary {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    def coreLibPath = "src/main/jniLibs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libQt5Core.so"
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("${coreLibPath}")
                }
            }
            QNetSharedLibrary {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    def networkLibPath = "src/main/jniLibs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libQt5Network.so"
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("${networkLibPath}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 18
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
            }
        }

        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    dependencies {
                        library "QtStaticLibrary" linkage "static"
                        library "QCoreSharedLibrary" linkage "shared"
                        library "QNetSharedLibrary" linkage "shared"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName = "communication"
            cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
            stl "gnustl_shared"

            cppFlags.add('-I' + file("/Volumes/Transcend/Qt/5.7/android_armv7/include").absolutePath)
            cppFlags.add('-I' + file("/Volumes/Transcend/Qt/5.7/android_armv7/include/QtCore").absolutePath)

            abiFilters.addAll([
                    "x86",
                    "armeabi-v7a"
            ])
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

It would be great if somebody tell what I'm doing wrong and why the error in this line of code:

```
QNetworkReply * reply = networkAccessManager.get(request);
```

only occurs on `x86` devices and on devices with Android version less then 6.0 and only from native Android project (from QtCreator all works without errors). Thanks for help.

Comment: You're default constructing the networkAcccessManager, which seems to be contrary to the documentation.  Could that be your problem?  See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html

Comment: @Hod Thanks for the comment, but this creation of the object is fully correct and does not conflict with the documentation

Comment: I doubt someone will help you with this without a stack trace. You have to run the debugger and print the backtrace, then you have to check if relevant objects have proper values. Also, have you checked your code with `valgrind` ? Maybe you have memory leaks or bad memory access before you issue network calls and thus you run QT internal calls with corrupt object values. It may run well on Intel because memory corruption occurs in different place for different platform, so on Android you are probably catching this bug badly because it corrupts your stack exactly where the code is.

Comment: In you last paragraph you say it runs Ok when you run it from Qt creator, but you mean that when you press run from Qt creator it works and if you build an app and deploy it on the same device it does not work ? .. if that true the error should be somewhere in the packaging and deploying procedure rather than in the code or it could even be a problem with permissions.